# Robot Framework: Excel datasheet with 7 rows of data. How to execute just one of them from the command line

Tags: excel, robotframework, data-driven-tests

I have a data driven test based on an excel file with 7 rows of data, representing 7 test scenarios.  I cannot get tagging to work in order to execute just one row of the excel file.  I've read a lot on how to use tags if the data is stored in the robot test itself or the robot test has 5 different tests, but cannot figure out how to apply it when using an excel datasheet and a test template.  My test is just one single keyword that I wanted repeated for all 7 lines of data.  But sometimes I want to run just one line.

[Edited to add]

The datasheet is an excel with
[Excel Datasheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kaF0.png)
I have the following in the test:

```
Library DataDriver  Datasheet/Data.xls     sheet_name=Data

Test Template    My Test

*** Test Cases ***
My Test

*** Keywords ***

My Test    
   step 1   
   step 2
```

Comment: There is more than one way to do a data driven test. Can you provide a [mcve] -- the shortest possible example that illustrates  how you're doing a data driven test?

Comment: I've added more to the initial post.  I hope it is detailed enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement something similar to below where you will call the template and at the same time give it tags (static, from data read from excel or somewhere else):

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test 1   [Template]   My Template
   [Tags]   myTag, ${data_tag}
   my first data
   my second data

*** Keywords ***
My Template
   ...
```

Comment: I appreciate the feedback Claudio.  However, I'm not able to get it to recognize ${data_tag} as something that's in the datasheet, even though I've added it to the worksheet.  I've googled a bit and it seems like the timing of when it does the test case vs when it reads the datasheet may be an issue.

Comment: Just have a test that reads the excel into data and set whatever variables you need as global in that test so you can use them in other tests

Comment: I think I see what you are saying.  I will try it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try robot framework Data driver library

https://github.com/Snooz82/robotframework-datadriver

it will execute your test for all data in excel